# Is it possible to use realm-java and realm-kotlin (kmm) in the same android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-java

I have several different realm database instances in the same project and I would like to migrate them one at a time from realm-java to realm-kotlin. Is it feasible? What were the pitfalls encountered?

They seem to have different package structure, and different plugins.

Comment: Realm's underlying data is platform agnostic so it's not only feasible it's fairly straightforward as well. Re-write your code in kotlin, point it to the Realm file stored on the device and you're done. If you're syncing, the first time you run your app the Realm file will be created from the data on the server so you can just use the file at the default location. There's not much more to it.